# Cannot resolve symbol gcm (Android Studio 0.8.9)

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, google-cloud-messaging

Im trying to use Google Cloud Messaging with Android Studio, but it cannot find android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService" and   the gcm and GcmIntent appears in read. I have intalled Google play services  v 6.1.11.
In the build.gradle i have compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11" as dependency.
How, i have that installed.
I had open the google play services directoy and i havent found gcm. I have gcm installed from sdk manager but still doesnt recognize .GCMBaseIntentService and .GcmIntentService

Answer (score 1):

`com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService` is an old deprecated class that belonged to the deprecated `gcm.jar`. Since you are using Google Play Services library, there's no need for you to use `GCMBaseIntentService`.

Comment: When you say no need to use GCMBaseIntentService, what would be used instead? I am working a project that someone else started years ago and they have a custom class extending GCMBaseIntentService.

Is there a new replacement class, or do I need to read deeper into this and find another to implement what they have done?

Comment: @JuiCe i have a same problem, have you found what i have to use instead..

Comment: @SagarChavada sorry but we've pushed GCM aside for the time being. Never ended up finding a solution

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you update or install 'Google Repository' on the SDK manager. Also make sure that you are pointing to the right SDK path.
Go to:

> File>Project Structure> SDK Location

Answer (score 0):

GCMBaseIntentService is depicted and part of play service lib (3.1+) so you don't have to add any other jar file. gcm.jar is obsolete now, you can find it in SDK also.

[image]

According to android documentation add below line in gradle.build file  (latest version)

> dependencies {
>     compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87"
>   }

For more info

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html